# Language file doesn't work (poeedit)

Tags: templates, language

I'm trying to translate a WordPress template. I went to language files, then opened that copy with Poedit and started translating to my language (persian).

After finishing the translation, I changed the WordPress language from the dashboard, but the language didn't change in the template settings panel, it stays on English. Any idea why this happens?

These are the language instructions from functions.php:

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'apress', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
```

Comment: Where did you keep the `mo` file?

Comment: the mo file is in language folder

Comment: 1. what is the name of your translation file. 2. Do you use `load_theme_textdomain` in any hook or standalone?

Comment: it's use standalone

Comment: the name of translation file is fa_IR

Answer (score 0):

According to docs, `load_theme_textdomain()` function should generally be called from within the after_setup_theme action hook.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_setup' );

function my_theme_setup(){
    load_theme_textdomain( 'apress', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
}
```